# GCM response success but no notifications delivered on ios device

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on cordova project and i need users to receive push notifications I used firebase with cordova plugin push and the GCM response was:

`GCM response :
{\"multicast_id\":6875962456318713515,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1509878580992374%39c6ff07f9fd7ecd\"}]}"`

but my ios device didn't show any notifications although on android devices it is working perfect and with sending from APN free tester my apple device receive the notification soon, i followed all the mentioned steps to make firebase  project and i uploaded the APN certificate and download .plist file and I am receiving the right gcm registration token (i mentioned it above) my project is cordova project and i didn't receive any errors during building from xcode, except:

`017-11-05 11:57:02.994: GCM | Invalid key in checkin plist: GMSInstanceIDDeviceDataVersion`

to my device or from gcm service really I don't what's happening please help me to make apple device to receive push notifications, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue it was very simple and silly it was the payload data GCM use notification instead of data when posting the request to the APN so the payload must be in a form like:

```
"notification" : {
    "body" : "test message",
    "title" : "app name"
}
```

I was using:

```
"data" : {
    "body" : "test message",
    "title" : "app name"
}
```

That was the trick although data is valid only with Android while notification is valid for both iOS and Android again (THNKS APPLE!!!)